# Searching For Stop Words When Language Is Overridden Doesn't Work As Expected

Tags: java, mongodb, text, indexing, stop-words

The following example attempts to demonstrate the effect of language selection on text index (and text search)

[MongoDB Documentation: Specify the Index Language within the Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/#specify-the-index-language-within-the-document)

```
final MongoDatabase db = initRandomDatabase();
final MongoCollection<Document> col1 = initCollection(db, "col1");
final String textField = "text";
final String languageField = "language";
int idCounter = 0;
col1.createIndex(new Document(textField, "text"), new IndexOptions().defaultLanguage("french"));

final String[] words = {"cat", "chat", "katze", "and", "et", "und"};
final String[] languages = {"english", "french", "german"};
for (final String word : words) {
    col1.insertOne(
            new Document(ID, idCounter++)
                    .append(textField, word)
    );
    for (final String language : languages) {
        col1.insertOne(
                new Document(ID, idCounter++)
                        .append(textField, word)
                        .append(languageField, language)
        );
    }
}

final String frenchStopWordToFind = "et";
final FindIterable<Document> frenchStopWordSearchResults = col1.find(new Document("$text", new Document("$search", frenchStopWordToFind)));
printTitledDocumentMongoIterable("French Stop Word To Find \"" + frenchStopWordToFind + "\"", frenchStopWordSearchResults);
```

The problem is when searching for `et` no results are returned even though there is language override in some documents.

I expected that for documents where `language` field is set to another language (not french), then the word `et` will be indexed and the search result will include it

Comment: what do you mean "there is language override" ?

Comment: when specifying field 'langauge, the language in that field overrides the default index language for that document. A documentation url has been added.

Comment: But you don't use language in the index https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/#use-any-field-to-specify-the-language-for-a-document. There is only default_language being used in your snippet.

Comment: If you don't specify default language while creating the index, the index will still be created with a default language of "english". In my snippet, if i were to remove the specified default language, then searching for the english stop word "and" will yield no results

Comment: Sorry nazz, I was probably not quite clear with my wording but the documentation behind the link I provided says it out loud - you need to **add name of the language field** to the index in addition to the default language. Have you read it?

Comment: Specifying language field is necessary only if you intend to use a field other than "language", this is not the case in my example. However, just to be sure, i specified the language field and the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Both the following languages

1. Language of the field (either inherited from the collection's text index or specified in the `language` field)
2. Language specified in the `$text` search query optional parameter `$language`

has to be languages within which the word-to-find must not be a stop word in order for that word to be found within the search query.

The default value of the optional `$language` parameter of the search query `$text` operator is the same as the default language of the index.

As the example in the question did not specify a different language for the `$text` query, the `$text` query used the same language as the index's. as a result, the word 'et' was considered a stop word a was not found.